# Python output a json style string

Tags: python, json

here defining a variable:

```
sms_param = '{\"website\":\"hello\"}'
```

and it print out ok like this : `{"website":"hello"}`, but i want to pass a dynamic value to its value, so its format should like this: `{\"website\":\"{0}\"}.format(msg)`, but it output a `KeyError`, I have no idea of this Error, and change all kinds of string format such as triple quotation and change `{0}` with `%s`, but all seems useless. how can i solve it.

Comment: Drop string manipulation, use [the proper json library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html). `json.dumps()` is your friend.

Comment: What's the point of those backslashes? You don't need them.

Comment: If you're gonna use `format`, you have to escape the curly braces: `'{{"website":"{0}"}}'.format(msg)`

Comment: Is there not transfer meaning symbol in python? i thought it will transfer double quote to ordinal string previously.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is using `json.loads()`

```
>>> sms_param = '{\"website\":\"hello\"}'
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(sms_param)
{'website': 'hello'}
```

What you can do is using `json.loads()` convert the json string to dictionary and then change the value, finally convert it back to string